# Magento Detect checkout success page

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm working with Magento 1.9 and have a PHP include file that I'm using to display facebook pixel code based on the page type. IE: cart, checkout, product details, catalog, cms...

I'm looking at the page request module, controller, action, etc.  However, I can't seem to find a way to determine if they're at /checkout/success/ or not.  If I try to look at the request URI it returns /checkout/cart/

Is there a class property or method that I can use to determine that the user is in fact on the order success page?

Comment: if you manually enter the url in browser it will redirect you to the cart page, to visit success page you have to place an order. Also the controller action for success in default magento is `checkout/onepage/success/`

Comment: @Piyush thanks for the help but I already know how to get to the pages and even though that is the correct action, the page doesn't return that when you call $this->getAction()->getActionName();

Comment: can you tell me where you have added this code?

Comment: I created a new PHP file and included it in the template's frontend page\html\header.phtml file.  Then I called it with getPageType($this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up working through it by looking at the current quote ID (which should be null), the current controller, and the last order ID.

```
function getPageType($page)
{
    $request    = $page->getRequest();
    $controller = $request->getControllerName();
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');

    if($session->getLastOrderId() && !$session->getQuoteId() && $controller == 'cart')
    {
        return 'success';
    }
}
```

After a purchase has been completed, the current quote is cleared. However, since we're still in the cart, then that means the purchase has been completed.  I check the last order id just to be sure there was a purchase.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName() == 'success'){
// code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also make use of the layout handle `checkout_onepage_success`.

Reference this in a layout of your custom module and in the referenced template file include the facebook pixel code.

```
<checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
        <reference name="after_body_start">
            <block type="core/template" template="example/fb/conversion.phtml" />
        </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

And, in `example/fb/conversion.phtml`, do the needful processing and include the facebook pixel code.

```
<script>
    fbq('track','Purchase', {
        value: <?php echo xxx ?>,
        currency: '<?php echo xxx ?>',
        content_ids: <?php echo xxx ?>,
        content_type: 'product',
        num_items: <?php echo xxx; ?>
    });
</script>
```